# Can not access Home directory

Tags: partitioning, home-directory

I tried to relocate my home directory. I previously used only 30GB of my hard disk, so I decided to get some additional space.

I make the steps from [here](http://goo.gl/9LzFUB). But something went wrong when I stopped at step 2: Copy the files from your current Home folder to the new Home folder.

I continued to the next steps. Now when I try to go enter some of the Home directories it gives me the following

```
This location could not be displayed.You do not have the permissions necessary to view the contents of “Downloads”.
```

What could I do? Format the home partition and did it again?

Comment: What is the permissions on your new home directory that you are unable to access? ls -al /home Eg = drwxr-xr-x 42 user group 4096 Jul 4 20:27 folder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do a

```
sudo chown $USER:$USER <your_problem_folder>
```

where `<your_problem_folder>` is the folder with which you have trouble.

Comment: That one works fine :)